# Convert a string with format dd-NameOfMonth-yy to a Date

Tags: java

I have a string in this format dd-NameOfMonth-yy

example : `String str="12-nov-12"`

And i would like to convert it to a `Date`.

I tried the following code but i got the error :

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-Sep-11"

```
DateFormat formatter = null;
Date convertedDate = null;
String ddMMMyy = "14-Sep-11";
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(ddMMMyy);
System.out.println("Date from dd-MMM-yy String in Java : " + convertedDate);
```

Comment: Works for me. What is your locale, i.e. is month 9 really abbreviated "Sep"?

Comment: yes is the month 9 , I didn't set the local but the local i need Frensh local. How can i set it? thx

Comment: Thank you Henry for your help , i just added the Local attribut to SimpleFormat() and it works very well: formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy",Locale.FRANCE);